# Checking for permissions for SHBrowseForFolder similar to GetSaveFileName, C++ / Win32

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I have a program that uses both SHBrowseForFolder, GetSaveFileName.

When I use GetSaveFileName and the directory chosen doesn't have the right permission it automatically shows an error that the current user doesn't have the proper permission.

I need a checking similar to this to happen when I use SHBrowseForFolder.

Have tried CreateDirectory but it succeeds if the directory chosen is C:, while GetSaveFileName would only allow admins to write here.

Comment: Use `IFileSaveDialog` and the `FOS_PICKFOLDERS` option

Answer (score 0):

You can check permissions using this:

1. GetProcessToken
2. GetTokenInformation (to get the tokenuser and SID for the user)
3. GetNamedSecurityInfo (to get the DACL for the given folder) and
4. BuildTrusteeWithSid(pTrustee, pSidUser);
5. GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl

For more details see [Check User’s Permissions On A File or Folder](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1881/Check-User-s-Permissions-On-A-File-or-Folder?msg=524105#xx524105xx) article.